# Change returning date from Propel in PHP

Tags: php, propel

I have a Database and I use Propel to get the data.
Now I have the following problem: 
I want to get the date from one Table and add 30 days on it. 
So something like this:

```
$invoicePayDay = $invoice->getCreationDay()->add(30 days)->format('d.m.Y');
```

I know that I can read the month, day and year separately and can than add 20 days and create a date from it again. but  properly there is a better way to do it with Propel like my example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return the date as a var than you can do

```
$date = date('d.m.Y', strtotime('+30 days', strtotime($returnDate)));
```

Comment: That works for me and is short, but that means also that there is no way to do is in the Propel Execution itself?

Comment: I don't know a way :(. You can always create such method in your invoice model.